# ie7 JSONP src 2020 characters limit

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

It seems I've hit a limit of 2020 characters when trying to send some information through JSONP on ie7.

If the src of the script is bigger than 2020 characters, ie7 just ignores the script. Is there some way around this?

(I know that a solution would be to split the data and let the server concatenate the request)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maximum URL length is 2,083 characters in [Internet Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427)

> Is there any way are this?

Use another browser? :) Only way is find a way to reduce the amount of data you are sending. Use a different format, try some sort of zipping algorithm, or do some strange multiple requests that can only lead to more complexity to your app.

Comment: Thanks! Guess I'll use the strange multiple requests option :) .Zipping the data would not guarantee all request to be in the 2083 limit

Answer (score -3):

Use the POST method, this one shouldn't have any problem with the length of your data.

Comment: You can't use the POST method with JSON-P. It works by loading a `<script>`.

Comment: Well I meant to use another library, like jQuery. jQuery can load json using the post method.

Comment: jQuery uses GET for jsonp. You can switch to post, but when it is on a different server it can not magically use post.

Comment: POST cannot be used for cross-origin requests on IE7.  Most likely, the OP specifically asked about JSONP because he needs cross-origin support.